# Delete multiple subdirectories having a particular filetype

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a parent folder of 100 sub-directories
in which 50 of them are having `.dlg` files and 50 of them are not having `.dlg` files

Now I would like to move those subfolders as a whole which is having `.dlg` files into another folder and work with those which are not having `.dlg` file.

Comment: Why does your question title say “Delete”  when your question is about moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find` command is a good match for this kind of task.

Let me first set up some files to testing purposes:

```
$ mkdir -p tmp/testing/{1..100}
$ find tmp/testing -mindepth 1 | shuf | head -50 | while read d; do touch "$d"/foo.dlg; done
```

That created a hundred directories, and a random 50 of them contain some file called `foo.dlg`. Now we want to move them to somewhere:

```
$ mkdir tmp/testing2/
$ find tmp/testing -type f -regex ".*\.dlg" -exec dirname {} + | while read d; do mv "$d" tmp/testing2/; done
```

This `find` command looks for all files with a .dlg extension under `tmp/testing` and execs `dirname` on them. The `dirname` command is happy to take a long list of files or directories, and it returns a list of directories corresponding to the arguments.

So after getting all those dirnames, we pass it into loop which does the moving. Naturally you could use `mv -v` if you want more verbose feedback about what happened.

Comment: Yay! Thanks alot @cryptarch it works! could you also be kind enough to help me with creating a list of filenames that is only having abc.pdbqt as the filetype but in the list file I want only as abc? or If I am having 100 various .pdbqts in a list file how to remove .pdbqt pattern? Thanks once again

Comment: @user396007 Sounds like you're after `basename`. It's kind of complementary to `dirname`: it will remove both leading directories and trailing suffixes. Check out `man basename`

Comment: Your answer fails for directory names that end with space (or tab) or that contain newline.  Also, it produces a lot of error messages if any subdirectory has more than one ``.dlg`` file.  P.S. Why not say ``-name *.dlg``?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dir; do
        ls -- "$dir/"*.dlg >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
        echo mv -v -- "$dir" /move/to/tmp/;
    done
' sh {} +
```

remove `echo` for the `mv` command which is used for dry-run to move the directories.